# Why does Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSI not exist in android studio?

Tags: android, opencv

I need to convert RGB to HSI because I need to get the hue and intensity channels. But Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSI does not exist in android studio. What methods can I use that produces the same output?

Answer (score 0):

Because there is not Android Studio, but OpenCV issue. You can convert RGB to HSI like in [this answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/62446/conversion-from-rgb-to-hsi/):

[image]